# Java: Jetty server with Vaadin 11 framework

Tags: java, jetty, vaadin, embedded-jetty

My goal is to configure a Jetty server to work with the Vaadin 11 framework.
What I was trying was the following:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Server server = new Server();
    final ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
    httpConnector.setPort(8080);
    final ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new VaadinServlet());
    contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setServer(server);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    server.addConnector(httpConnector);
    server.setHandler(contextHandler);
    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Route("/")
public class MainView extends Div {
    public MainView() {
        System.out.println("main");
        setText("aha bye");
    }
}
```

But the MainView is never called.
How can I tell Jetty to forward the requests to Vaadin?

Comment: Short answer since I'm on a mobile. You have to enable Jetty's annotation scanning so that it can find `@Route` annotated classes. Might also be something else to add to make it run Vaadin's `ServletContainerInitializer` implementations.

Comment: Thank you @LeifÅstrand - I just posted an answer here with the way you described - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

> But this will still not work as you expect. Why? Because you have 2 different contexts (`contextHandler` and `context`) on the same contextPath `/`.
>
> But again, this seems backwards, as your `WebAppContext` has no resource base or war declared, so it's not doing anything for you in your sample code.

[Joakim Erdfelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775715/joakim-erdfelt) is absolutely right. I messed up the code with two contexts **and** I either have to set a resource base or a war-file. Many thanks to you as you pointed out the way to the solution!

Thanks to [Leif Åstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2376954/leif-%c3%85strand) too for the hint of finding all classes with the `@Route` annotation!

I separated the server code from the "client" code and build the war-file for the jetty server.

What I use as a working solution is the following:

```
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setServer(httpServer);
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new TestServlet()), "/*");
context.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
context.setExtractWAR(true);
context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
context.setInitParameter("ui", MainUI.class.getCanonicalName());
httpServer.setHandler(context);
```

In the `Testservlet` (extending `VaadinServlet`) I have the following two methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void findRouteClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> routeClasses = ReflectionUtils.findClassesWithAnnotation(Route.class,
    "com.example.myproject");

    this.routeClasses = new HashSet<>();

    for (final Class<?> clazz : routeClasses)
        this.routeClasses.add((Class<? extends Component>) clazz);
}

@Override
protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
    final ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    final Object routeRegistryObject = context.getAttribute(RouteRegistry.class.getName());

    if (routeRegistryObject == null)
        throw new ServletException("routeRegistryObject is null");

    if ((routeRegistryObject instanceof RouteRegistry) == false)
        throw new ServletException("routeRegistryObject is not of type RouteRegistry");

    final RouteRegistry routeRegistry = (RouteRegistry) routeRegistryObject;
    findRouteClasses();

    try {
        routeRegistry.setNavigationTargets(routeClasses);
    } catch (final InvalidRouteConfigurationException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

    super.servletInitialized();
}
```

All classes with the annotation `com.vaadin.flow.router.Route` are seached and then set as the navigation targets.

Answer (score 1):

```java
server.setHandler(contextHandler);
server.setHandler(context);
```

You replaced your `contextHandler` with the `context` with that code.

Try this instead ...

```
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(contextHandler);
handlers.addHandler(context);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // to report errors if nothing above matches
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

But this will still not work as you expect.
Why?  Because you have 2 different contexts (`contextHandler` and `context`) on the same contextPath `/`.

The first context in your `HandlerList` will be used, and the next one will never be called.
Why?  Because once you enter a context, you do not exit it (that context MUST serve a response, even an error).

You could just modify your `WebAppContext` to include the `VaadinServlet` (eliminating the need for `ServletContextHandler` entirely)

eg:

```
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new VaadinServlet());
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
```

But again, this seems backwards, as your `WebAppContext` has no resource base or war declared, so it's not doing anything for you in your sample code.

If it were me, and I'm using [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty), I would avoid using a `WebAppContext` entirely and just stick with the `ServletContextHandler` only.